# "no such file to load -- treetop/runtime" running "rake jobs:work"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, treetop

when i try and run the "rails server" or "rake jobs:work" i get the error:
"no such file to load -- treetop/runtime"

full trace:

macbook-pro-2:domain ryan$ rake jobs:work --trace(in /Applications/htdocs/domain) rake aborted!
no such file to load -- treetop/runtime
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mail-2.2.14/lib/mail.rb:68:in `require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mail-2.2.14/lib/mail.rb:68
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mail-2.2.14/lib/mail.rb:61:in`each'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mail-2.2.14/lib/mail.rb:61
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.2/lib/delayed/performable_mailer.rb:1:in `require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.2/lib/delayed/performable_mailer.rb:1
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.2/lib/delayed_job.rb:5:in`require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.2/lib/delayed_job.rb:5
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in `require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64:in`require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `each'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in`require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:51:in `each'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:51:in`require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler.rb:112:in `require'
/ApApplications/htdocs/domain/config/application.rb:7
/opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`gem_original_require'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Applications/htdocs/domain/Rakefile:4
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in`load'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2017:in`load_rakefile'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in`load_rakefile'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2000:in `run'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in`standard_exception_handling'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/opt/local/bin/rake:19:in`load'
/opt/local/bin/rake:19

in my Gemfile i have:
"gem 'delayed_job'"

Answer (score 1):

Run it through `bundle exec`: `bundle exec rails server` and `bundle exec rake jobs:work`

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue on ruby 1.8 but not on ruby 1.9
and solved it by adding this to my Gemfile

```
gem 'treetop', :platforms => :ruby_18
```

Answer (score 0):

turns out i had old gems installed that were causing the issue

mail (2.2.14, 2.2.12, 2.2.11, 2.2.10)
treetop (1.4.9, 1.4.8)

i uninstalled the old ones and everything works great now